# html image not printing for some user logins/profiles

Tags: html, image, printing, user-profile

I have an HTML file that displays data with an image overlay form.

The image is called in the HTML using the following:

```
<IMG class=img-print-class src="\\servername\blah\blah\blah\*.PNG">
<IMG class=img-view-class src="\\servername\blah\blah\blah\*.PNG">
```

All users can display the document correctly. But, for certain users, the image overlay does not print, only the data.

There seems to be something tied to the user login profile that is impacting whether or not the overlay prints.  It is not a security access issue, because the affected users are able to navigate to the server that stores the image and right-click print it.  So, they have the security rights required to access the image.

Is there something in the windows profile that would affect this? 
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why the tag didn't display:

Comment: <IMG class=img-print-class src="\\servername\blah\blah\blah\*.PNG">

Comment: Does it work if you have the web page accessing the image via HTTP?

Comment: If we bring up IE11 and type the server location in the address bar, the users in question are able to view the image.  I think that is what you were asking?  We have not had any issues with viewing - only printing.

Comment: Actually, this is interesting.  If we bring up the image through the address, it displays correctly.  When just the image is displayed in the browser, it prints correctly from the IE11.  However, when it is pulled up as part of a document using HTML, it displays correctly but does not print correctly.

Comment: I have done lots more problem determination today.  When I strip all of the data element tags out of the html and only include the <img> tag, the user is able to print the image.  When I reintroduce an id reference in the style section, such as #Info---1-Name {position: absolute; left:21px; top:10px;} with a corresponding entry in the body section, such as <DIV id=Info---1-Name>JOHN DOE</DIV>, only the data prints and the image disappears.

Comment: Have you tested with more than 1 browser? I have previously had issues with printing in IE where Chrome had no such issues.

Comment: Yes, in Chrome, both the image and the data print.  There are other formatting issues, but both pieces print.  The application creating the HTML is not supported in Chrome.  WE have also further isolated the problem to be tied to a user profile on a specific PC.  The user can log on at another PC and print successfully.   And, I can log on to the users PC and print successfully.  It seems to be tied to the user profile on a specific machine. It will not be practical to delete and recreate user profiles, so I am trying to understand what specifically in the profile may be causing the problem.

Comment: Could there be something in a browser add-on that is interfering?  When I am able, I am thinking of disabling add-ons. If that doesn't impact it, then possibly reseting IE11 Advanced Tab options to original settings?

Comment: Also try to add the location of the image to the Trusted Sites or Intranet Sites in the IE zones lists. It may help.